# ubuntu unable to run .exe program using wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, mono

I want to tun a  `.exe` program using wine in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but it fails

What i run:

```
wine app.exe
```

What it returns:

```
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
005c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
005c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
INTEL-MESA: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

INTEL-MESA: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
Failed to run module constructor due to (null) assembly:C:\windows\mono\mono-2.0\lib\mono\4.5\mscorlib.dll type:TypeInitializationException member:(null)
```

I also ran `sudo apt install mono-complete` but nothing changes

can anyone help?